# Match unique patterns in string - Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, search, pattern-matching

I have a list of strings called txtFreeForm:

```
['Add roth Sweep non vested money after 5 years of termination',
 'Add roth in-plan to the 401k plan.]
```

I need to check if only 'Add roth' exists in the sentence. To do that i used this

```
for each_line in txtFreeForm:
    match = re.search('add roth',each_line.lower())
    if match is not None:
        print(each_line)
```

But this obviously returns both the strings in my list as both contain 'add roth'. Is there a way to exclusively search for 'Add roth' in a sentence, because i have a bunch of these patterns to search in strings.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why shouldn't the two strings be returned if they both contain "Add roth"?

Comment: `if 'add roth' in each_line.lower(): ...` is a much cheaper way to solve this roblem. No `re` required.

Comment: i agree that 'in' is a cheaper way to do it. @AndreiSavin i know it will return both if found in text. but i am looking for a way to differentiate between sentences that contain only 'add roth' and those that contain 'add roth in plan'

Answer (score 0):

Can you fix this problem by using the .Length property of strings? I'm not an experienced Python programmer, but here is how I think it should work:

```
for each_line in txtFreeForm:
    match = re.search('add roth',each_line.lower())
    if (match is not None) and (len(txtFreeForm) == len("Add Roth")):
        print(each_line)
```

Basically, if the text is in the string, AND the length of the string is exactly to the length of the string "Add Roth", then it must ONLY contain "Add Roth".

I hope this was helpful.

**EDIT:**

I misunderstood what you were asking. You want to print out sentences that contain "Add Roth", but not sentences that contain "Add Roth in plan". Is this correct?

How about this code?

```
for each_line in txtFreeForm:
    match_AR = re.search('add roth',each_line.lower())
    match_ARIP = re.search('add roth in plan',each_line.lower())
    if (match_AR is True) and (match_ARIP is None):
        print(each_line)
```

This seems like it should fix the problem. You can exclude any strings (like "in plan") by searching for them too and adding them to the comparison.

Comment: Then why not say `each_line.lower() == 'add roth'` directly?

Comment: @Michael Kemp your code will return again both the strings from the list

Comment: @AndreiSavin what you are suggesting is exact match. not add roth being a part of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You're close :) Give this a shot:

```
for each_line in txtFreeForm:
    match = re.search('add roth (?!in[-]plan)',each_line.lower())
    if match is not None:
        print(each_line[match.end():])
```

**EDIT:**
Ahhh I misread... you have a LOT of these.  This calls for some more aggressive magic.

```
import re
from functools import partial

txtFreeForm = ['Add roth Sweep non vested money after 5 years of termination',
               'Add roth in-plan to the 401k plan.']


def roths(rows):
    for row in rows:
        match = re.search('add roth\s*', row.lower())
        if match:
            yield row, row[match.end():]

def filter_pattern(pattern):
    return partial(lazy_filter_out, pattern)


def lazy_filter(pattern):
    return partial(lazy_filter, pattern)


def lazy_filter_out(pattern, rows):
    for row, rest in rows:
        if not re.match(pattern, rest):
            yield row, rest

def magical_transducer(bad_words, nice_rows):
    magical_sentences = reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), [roths] + map(filter_pattern, bad_words), nice_rows)
    for row, _ in magical_sentences:
        yield row

def main():
    magic = magical_transducer(['in[-]plan'], txtFreeForm)
    print(list(magic))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To explain a bit about what's happening hear, you mentioned you have a LOT of these words to process.  The traditional way you might compare two groups of items is with nested for-loops.  So,

```
results = []
for word in words:
    for pattern in patterns:
        data = do_something(word_pattern)
        results.append(data)
for item in data:
   for thing in item:
      and so on...
         and so fourth...
```

I'm using a few different techniques to attempt to achieve a "flatter" implementation and avoid the nested loops.  I'll do my best to describe them.

```
**Function compositions**
# You will often see patterns that look like this:
x = foo(a)
y = bar(b)
z = baz(y)

# You may also see patterns that look like this:
z = baz(bar(foo(a)))

# an alternative way to do this is to use a functional composition
# the technique works like this:
z = reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), [foo, bar, baz], a)
```

Comment: wow. i dont even understand the functions. let me do some reading and then get back to you. thanks in advance

Comment: Oh wow, sorry about that!  I should've been more clear in my post.  I'll see if I can some extra details about what this is doing.